# Need help converting many if statements to a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ihave read a bunch on Javascript loops but can not find anything to fit this type thing.

I have a web page where a user will define jobs by the tasks that are associated with the job.  As they pick a new job and pick the tasks the tasks are written to the DB in a line item table.  The Job definition portion of this is loaded in an iframe on the parent page.
I have text boxes numbered with and id of jb1 to jb10 on the parent.  Each text box will hold the jobid of a job, with a text box only being written upon the first task of a job being submitted.  I hope this is clear to someone.

I have written a very basic javascript to check the value of test (initially set to 0 then incremented to 1 when the first task is submitted)

What I would like to have help with is how to change this 50 some odd lines of javascript into a loop to not use so many lines.

This is the script:

```
<script>
function chkjobnum() {
var id = $("#test").val();
if (id <= 0) {
var id1 = parent.top.$("input#jb1").val();
if (id1 <= 0){
    $("#test").val(1);
     parent.top.$("input#jb1").val( $("#job").val() );
     return;    }
var id2 = parent.top.$("input#jb2").val();
if (id2 <= 0){
    $("#test").val(1);
    parent.top.$("input#jb2").val( $("#job").val() );
    return; }
var id3 = parent.top.$("input#jb3").val();
if (id3 <= 0){
    $("#test").val(1);
    parent.top.$("input#jb3").val( $("#job").val() );
    return; }
var id4 = parent.top.$("input#jb4").val();
if (id4 <= 0){
    $("#test").val(1);
    parent.top.$("input#jb4").val( $("#job").val() );
    return; }   
var id5 = parent.top.$("input#jb5").val();
if (id5 <= 0){
    $("#test").val(1);
    parent.top.$("input#jb5").val( $("#job").val() );
    return; }
var id6 = parent.top.$("input#jb6").val();
if (id6 <= 0){
    $("#test").val(1);
     parent.top.$("input#jb6").val( $("#job").val() );
    return; }
var id7 = parent.top.$("input#jb7").val();
if (id7 <= 0){
    $("#test").val(1);
    parent.top.$("input#jb7").val( $("#job").val() );
    return; }
var id8 = parent.top.$("input#jb8").val();
if (id8 <= 0){
    $("#test").val(1);
    parent.top.$("input#jb8").val( $("#job").val() );
    return; }
var id9 = parent.top.$("input#jb9").val();
if (id9 <= 0){
    $("#test").val(1);
    parent.top.$("input#jb9").val( $("#job").val() );
    return; }   
var id10 = parent.top.$("input#jb10").val();
if (id10 <= 0){
    $("#test").val(1);
    parent.top.$("input#jb10").val( $("#job").val() );
    return; }
}                       
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like the following:

```
<script>
function chkjobnum() {
var id = $("#test").val();
if (id <= 0) {
     for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
         var idi = parent.top.$("input#jb"+i).val();
         if (idi <= 0) {
             $("#test").val(1);
             parent.top.$("input#jb" + i).val( $("#job").val() );
             return;
         }
      }
}                       
}
</script>
```

Comment: That is what i came up with also thank you so much everyone for your input

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started

```
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    var id = parent.top.$("input#jb"+i).val();
    if (id <= 0){
        $("#test").val(i);
         parent.top.$("input#jb"+i).val( $("#job").val() );
         return;    
    }
}
```

Comment: That almost worked I wrapped the what you posted in an additional if statement to first check the value of test then proceed accordingly.  how do I post the working code to try to help others?